# Retrieve user messages from a table and echo them relative to date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

OK, so I'm doing a little query here that retrieves all messages from two users IDs and then echos them out to the browser. This is all working fine and it echos out the messages relative to date sent.

But I now want to accomplish two queries and echo them out in order to date. So I'm pulling in all rows that have a sender ID and receiver ID that match, then I need to do the same query but with the IDs reversed. So in turn I'll be grabbing all conversation from the two users. Then I want to echo them out to the browser in order of date so thier conversation makes sense to them.

Here's what I currently have in operation and it gives me the desired results. But I need to bring in the other query reversed.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM msgs
             WHERE recipientid = '{$_SESSION['rider_id']}'
             AND authorid = '{$riderid}' ORDER BY datesent DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);        
//If an error with the query, report the error
if (!$result) {
    echo "Error with the database call to grab your message author.";
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $msgid = $row['id'];
    $authorid = $row['authorid'];
    $datesent = $row['datesent'];
    $message = $row['message'];                         
    ?>
    <div class="msgcontainer">
    <li>
        <img alt="<?php echo $authorrider['ridertag']; ?>"
        class="pimg" src="<?php echo $authorrider['profileimg']; ?>">
        <div class="globalfont"><?php echo $message; ?></div>
    </li>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some like this should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM msgs 
WHERE (recipientid = '{$_SESSION['rider_id']}' AND authorid = '{$riderid}') 
OR (authorid = '{$_SESSION['rider_id']}' AND recipientid = '{$riderid}')
ORDER BY datesent DESC
```

It's untested but I'm pretty confident it should fit the bill.

Comment: Unreal, let me try this, learning the mysql syntax has been tricky for me.

Comment: Im getting,

YOU HAVE AN ERROR IN YOUR SQL SYNTAX; CHECK THE MANUAL THAT CORRESPONDS TO YOUR MYSQL SERVER VERSION FOR THE RIGHT SYNTAX TO USE NEAR 'WHERE (AUTHORID = '36' AND RECIPIENTID = '25') ORDER BY DATESENT DESC' AT LINE 1

Comment: Also don't forget to protect yourself from SQL injections. Read this article as a start http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059 . (skim to the "Security" section).

Comment: Try my edit, it might just be `WHERE (...) OR (...)`

Comment: This works! Nice! Thankyou so much! Now on to make them differrent so we can read them nicer.. Thanks mate!